# DW01 2s protection

Tags: lithium-ion, protection, circuit-protection, lithium, undervoltage

I want to protect 2 18650 batteries with single DW01.
The problem is how to increase the protection voltage on DW01 .
I have read that I should use voltage divider on VCC pin. I just want to make sure 18650 wont turn into hand grenade.

**HERE IS MY SCHEMATIC**

[image: schematic]

Comment: yeah, or alternatively, many marketed BMSs are adjusted for 2S, 3S, or even more.

Comment: @ChristophorusHansen  Welcome to SE EE. The question is 3 years old - I've converted your answer into a comment (and I realise  the system does not allow you to comment initially so that may be what you would have preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: The DW01 is, according to its [datasheet](http://www.haoyuelectronics.com/Attachment/TP4056-modules/DW01-P_DataSheet_V10.pdf) (first line, first two words; emphasis mine) a

> **One Cell** Lithium-ion/Polymer Battery Protection IC

If it had the capability to really protect two cells in series, they would've marketed it that way.

So, while you can certainly sense a situtation that is definitely overvoltage *for both*, you won't be able to sense the (likely) situation that one cell failed and you're now overloading the second.

So, your approach is inherently bad, and you should not use a DW01 to protect two cells. Simple as that. Wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks, so I should use onw DW01 for each cell separately .Right ?